# get textfield in tableview cell when tap Save button and store in dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, textfield

I have 2 section with each 16 rows,and how to get all textfield value in tableview cell? want to store it when I tap save button.

and I already retrive simulate data from firebase database put in String:AnyObject,and show it on tableview.

how to get value like textfield or switch in tableviewCell?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabaseUI



class SettingLabelTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var BitArray:[String] = ["M0","M1","M2","M3","M4","M5","M6","M0","M8"
        ,"M9","M10","M11","M12","M13","M14","M15"]
    var WordArray:[String] = ["D0","D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D0","D8"
        ,"D9","D10","D11","D12","D13","D14","D15"]
    var DeviceKey:String?
    var Ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
    var allCellsText = [String]()
    @IBAction func SaveButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {


        /*self.Ref.setValue(dict, withCompletionBlock:
        { (error, dbref) in

        })*/
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Ref = device.child("DEVICE").child(DeviceKey!).child("SETTINGS").child("LABEL")
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        Ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if !snapshot.exists(){
                print("not exist")
                csGolbal.g_NameAry.removeAll()
                self.dict.removeAll()
            }
            else{
                self.dict.removeAll()
                self.dict = (snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject])!


                /*for item in snapshot.value as! [String : String]{
                    csGolbal.g_NameAry.append([item.key:item.value])
                }*/
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if section == 0
        {
            return BitArray.count
        }
        else
        {
            return WordArray.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelNameCell", for: indexPath) as! LabelNameTableViewCell

        cell.LabelTitle.text = BitArray[indexPath.row]
        if dict.count > 0{
            cell.txtName.text = dict["M"+String(indexPath.row)] as? String ?? "null"

        }
    return cell
    }
```

my tableviewCell

```
class LabelNameTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var LabelTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like this

```
 @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       var dict: [String:String] = [:]
       for (i,bit) in bitArray.enumarate() {
           let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as! LabelNameTableViewCell
           dict[bit] = cell.txtName.text
       }
       for (i,word) in wordArray.enumarate() {
           let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 1)) as! LabelNameTableViewCell
           dict[word] = cell.txtName.text
       }
      // dict ---- "M0": "some text" ...
      //then store it 
    }
```

p.s. In swift variables and function must start with lowercase character, see apple standard library functions.

Comment: is this can use in dynamic cell? console said:unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: sorry for late response, it seems you must cast  cell, i edited answer